# PopenSpawn and ftp command

Tags: python, windows, pexpect

question - i am trying to make minimal example with latest pexpect,
but cant get to working basic example(src is below) in following
enviroment:
windows 10, 64bit python 3.4
command is ftp localhost ( server is filezila, running on localhost)
i am aware windows support in pexpect,  is marked as experimental, but still, it would be usefull to get it working ..
problem:
if in code below i use

```
co.expect("",timeout=30)
```

, then scripts works, because it is not waiting for prompt after login... but as i need to interact and put more complex query, i need to use
`co.expect("ftp>",timeout=30)`

but at that moment, pexpect wait till timeout.. i found, in popen_spawn.py, nothing is coming. is it possible self.proc.stdout.fileno() is buffering, and waiting indefinetly, till buffer is filled ?

```
import pexpect
from pexpect import popen_spawn
import sys

try:
    hostname = "127.0.0.1"
    co = pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn('ftp localhost',encoding="utf-8")
    co.logfile = sys.stdout
    co.timeout = 4
    co.expect(":")
    co.sendline("test")
    co.expect(".*word:.*")
    co.sendline("test123")
    co.expect("",timeout=30)
    co.sendline('dir')
    co.expect('ftp>')
    co.close()


except Exception as e:
    print(co)
```

Comment: Show the full dump of the timeout error.